# Accept any value in POST JSON using API Blueprint

Tags: json, post, apiblueprint

Is there any way to make POST request of API Blueprint to accept any value?

Right now I have:

```
### Google [POST]
Login with Google

+ token (string) - google token

+ Request (application/json)
      {
          "token": "google"
      }

+ Response 200 (application/json)
      {
        "token": "xyz",
      }
```

And nothing apart from exactly the same body as as described is being consumed by Drakov.

Comment: You parameter could be causing issues. token ( string  ) could be set to optional. And, I think `token` is more of an attribute than a parameter. As far as my understanding about API Blueprint goes, Paramters are part of URL. I presume you want Parameter in the body. Also, aren't you putting your token in the header ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema, instead of hardcoded values.

- Request(application/vnd.aconex.pdfmerge.job.v1.1+json)

  - Headers

    ```
    Accept: application/vnd.pdfmerge.job.v1.1+json
    ```
  - Schema

    ```
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "zipFilePath": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "mergedFilePath": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "fileName": {
           "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "zipFilePath",
        "status",
        "mergedFilePath",
        "id",
        "fileName"
      ]
    }
    ```